# Set commands for a control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, devexpress

I am using `DevExpress` for a `WPF` application, I want to hit a toggle button and make the contents in a `richTextBox` bold, the manual which is provided [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9148) suggests to use `ToggleFontBoldCommand` as the command. In my WPF application in the `xaml` file I have added the following code:

```
<telerik:RadToggleButton CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=doc}" Command="com:ToggleFontBoldCommand" Content="B"/>
```

`doc` is a richTextBox. `com` is the namespace of DevExpress commands' namespaces `(xmlns:com="clr-namespace:DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands; assembly=DevExpress.RichEdit.v16.1.Core")`.
 The point is that `Visual Studio` can not find the command. I believe that I am wrong with the `CommandTarget` but I do not know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just using the standard WPF `ToggleButton` and `TextBox` in this answer, but I believe the solution should also work with your `telerik` and `DevExpress` controls.

If all you want is to make the text in the `RichTextBox` **bold** when the `RadToggleButton` has been clicked you should be able to side step the whole command thing and use something similar to the following:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="BoldToggle" />
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=BoldToggle}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

The style on the `TextBox` changes the `FontWeight` property from "Normal" to "Bold" when the `ToggleButton`'s `IsChecked` property is "true".

Does this get you what you need?

Comment: sorry but I need the use of Commands not triggers. my question was a typical problem facing `WPF applications`